# Assign variable value dynamically to Regex captured string

Tags: regex, powershell, templating

I'm trying to cobble togther a simple templating functionality with PowerShell.

So I have this text from a file or DB

```
$text = "Dear [PERSON], you have been chosen for a special award my the Management of [COMPANY]"
$PERSON = 'Ahmadu Samuel'
$COMPANY = 'SuperGlobal Limited'
```

I am trying to use the second capturing parenthesis (which retrieves 'PERSON'), then `Get-Variable` to retrieve the value of the variable `$PERSON`, like so:

```
$content = $txt -replace '([\{\[](\w+)[\}\]])', (gv '$2').value
```

Now, `(gv 'PERSON').Value` correctly produces `Ahmadu Samuel`. But with the above, I get an error like this:

```
gv : Cannot find a variable with the name '$2'
```

Shouldn't `(gv '$2').Value` do likewise? If not, how can I manipulate this expression to dynamically assign the variable value to this captured string?

Comment: `[Regex]::Replace($text,'([\{\[](\w+)[\}\]])',{param($Match)Get-Variable $Match.Groups[2].Value -ValueOnly})`

Comment: Thank you @PetSerAl. Your comment here did absolutely work. But I must confess that if I had to depend only on the other page, it would have been much tougher for me to arrive at this specific solution. (i.e. there is a significant difference in scenarios) So, do you still think this question should be closed? Or is it better to put up your comment as an answer?

Comment: I hardly can put something into answer to this question, that can help future readers more than answer to referenced question. So, I have no intention to put my comment as answer.